# python dictionary definition that contains one line of code - how to add more

Tags: python

In python is there a way to print out `i` and `j` in this line of code?

```
sources = {i: self.path_cost(i, target) for i, j in set}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not as it is written currently. (Edit: see AKX's answer, it *is* possible.) You'll have to rewrite the dict comprehension into a loop. Note that `set` is a built-in name, so not a good choice for a variable. Choose a better name! In addition, `i` and `j` are very general and it might be useful to rename them to something more clear.

```
sources = {}
for i, j in set:
    print(i, j)
    sources[i] = self.path_cost(i, target)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, kind of, but it's ugly and you really don't want to do this.

The idea is that the `print()` function has a side effect of printing things while returning `None`.

Since all elements of a tuple must be evaluated, we pack that into a tuple for its side effect only, then do the actual work in the second element of the tuple, and finally just grab the second element.

```py
sources = {i: (print(i, j), self.path_cost(i, target))[1] for i, j in set}
```

But again, please don't do this for anything other than temporary debugging purposes.

Comment: Cheeky. I like it.

Comment: This is very clever! (But as you say, very ugly and probably should not be used unless *for the fun of it*.)

Comment: This can be made shorter, abusing the facts that Python conditional expressions evaluate to the truthy operand rather than booleans and that `print` returns `None`: `sources = {i: print(i, j) or self.path_cost(i, target) for i, j in set}` It should also be a tiny bit faster since we do not create a temp tuple

Answer (score 1):

This could be also a solution:

```
def print_ij_and_return_i(i, j):
    print(i, j)
    return i

sources = {i: self.path_cost(print_ij_and_return_i(i, j), target) 
           for i, j in set}
```